# R: ggplot2 histogram fill dodge - prevent partial overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a histogram with ggplot2 comparing 2 periods of time. I want the bars to dodge (i.e. plot side-by-side) and not stack. I've tried this:

```
qplot(region, data = data, fill = month) +
  labs(y = "Sales", fill = "") +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

The `dodge` partially works but I'm still getting overlap:

[image]

How can I get the bars to position side-by-side properly?

**Update**

Output of `dput(head(data, 20))` as requested by @RuiBarradas in the comments:

```
structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("May 2018", 
"May 2019 (so far)"), class = "factor"), region = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Abbotsford", "Agassiz", "Bowen Island", 
"Burnaby East", "Burnaby North", "Burnaby South", "Chilliwack", 
"Cloverdale", "Coquitlam", "Cultus Lake", "Harrison Hot Springs", 
"Hope", "Islands-Van. & Gulf", "Ladner", "Langley", "Maple Ridge", 
"Mission", "N. Delta", "New Westminster", "North Surrey", "North Vancouver", 
"Pemberton", "Pitt Meadows", "Port Coquitlam", "Port Moody", 
"Richmond", "Rosedale", "Sardis", "South Surrey White Rock", 
"Squamish", "Sunshine Coast", "Surrey", "Tsawwassen", "Vancouver East", 
"Vancouver West", "West Vancouver", "Whistler", "Yarrow", "Harrison Mills / Mt Woodside"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Removing `fill = ""` from `labs` doesn't solve it. `geom_bar` doesn't have `fill = ""` in it.

Comment: Right, sorry, typo. And the data, if possible? (Could be one of R's built-in datasets.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I updated the question with `dput(head(data, 20))` per your request.

Comment: The `dput` output shows only three bars and it is not reflecting the issue you raised.  May be `geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))`

Comment: @RuiBarradas still doesn't work. I exported the data to a CSV using `write.csv(data, file = "data.csv")` and it's available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9nxzo1cmbwwfsa/data.csv?dl=0 . I can reproduce it by importing it (`data <- read.csv("data.csv")`) and plotting.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I started a brand new session in RStudio, then ran these 3 commands and was able to reproduce the problem: `library(ggplot2)` `data <- read.csv("data.csv")` `qplot(region, data = data, fill = month) + labs(y = "Sales", fill = "") + geom_bar(position = "dodge")`

Comment: Maybe it's a `qplot` thing, with `ggplot(data, aes(x = region, fill = month)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(y = "Sales")` it works as expected.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem too, see my previous comment for a possible solution.

Comment: @RuiBarradas You're right. `ggplot` works perfectly! Thank you! Can you paste that as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer?  It's bizarre that `qplot` doesn't work. I thought it was just a proxy for `ggplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is a `qplot` error, that can be reproduced with the data in the OP's link and the question's code.

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(region, data = data, fill = month) +
  labs(y = "Sales") +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

But with `ggplot` everything works as expected.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = region, fill = month)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  labs(y = "Sales")
```

[image]